# What is the name of the second tool

Tags: hand-tools, tools

[image]
Can somebody please help me out by naming the second tool in the row of tools in this image ? Thank you[image]

Comment: This may not be a woodworking tool, as the syringe isn't and the tool along the bottom isn't either. It could merely be the detached handle from something larger, even possibly a big piece of equipment.

Comment: Ok I understand, I was only wondering because today I found the same exact tool with the angled neck and curved tip outside my development and for the life of me I just can't find out what it is.

Comment: Based on the offset of the hook and the spinning capability of the handle, I'd take a wild guess that it's a twisting tool of some form. Would one use such a tool to make DIY barbed wire? A DIY rope making rig?

Answer (score 5):

Aha! I found it deep in the recesses of my alleged mind, and on The Google too. It's a rebar wire twisting tool. A length of wire with loops at each end is wrapped around an intersection of rebar. The tool passes through the loops and is spun to rapidly secure the rebar together, preventing it from shifting during the pour.

An auction posted to eBay also suggests that it is a rope twisting tool for the farm.

[image: rebar twisting tool]

Uh oh, not a wood working tool!

Comment: I never used one of these as an Ironworker, pliers being what everyone out of my hall used, (pliers have the advantage of being able to cut wire also) but I have seen these being used commonly in other countries with rebar and they are also common on other wire binding applications like farm usage. While technically not a woodworking tool, I can assure you that plenty off wood has been wired together.

Comment: These are used with a roll of tie wires that have pre-formed loops at both ends - I have two of them and use them for concrete rebar tying. You can live without the tool, but it's far faster with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

That is a spring puller. It appears home made. It is to reach into a tight place & pull up a coil spring. Or to unhook a coil spring.